# DASL Property: PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED giving a null value on incoming mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to parse Outlook email data to an Excel worksheet. I want to tag incoming mail as either "Incoming", "Replied", "Replied all" and "Forwarded".

The use case is to check mails which haven't been replied to. I want to get this resolved but PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003) is null.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const xlUp As Long = -4162 'Set the enumeration for Excel's xlup
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents sentItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Flagged").Items
  Set sentItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
  
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ExApp As Object
Dim ExWb As Object
Dim Attach As Attachment
Dim AttachFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim EmailRow As Long
Dim EmailText As String
Dim AttachRow As Long
Dim AttachNum As Long
Dim FileNumb As Long
Dim ErrNumb As Long
Dim WkBkOpen As Boolean
Dim oPA As Outlook.propertyaccessor
Dim PropName, Responded As String


If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = Item
    FileName = "C:\Users\Folder\Folder\EMAIL_MANAGER.xlsm" 'Customize this to your workbook location
    If FileName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please add a full file name for your Excel application"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    'Determine If Excel File is open or not
    On Error Resume Next
    FileNumb = FreeFile() 'Get Free File #
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #FileNumb ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Close FileNumb 'Close the file.
    ErrNumb = Err 'Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0 'Turn error checking back on.


    Select Case ErrNumb 'Check to see which error occurred
    Case 0 ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        WkBkOpen = False 'Error number for "Permission Denied
    Case 70 'File is already opened by another user.
        WkBkOpen = True
    Case Else ' Another error occurred.
        Error ErrNumb
    End Select


'Start Excel Application
On Error Resume Next
Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'Set EXCEL application object
On Error GoTo 0
If ExApp Is Nothing Then
Set ExApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Open Excel
End If
ExApp.Visible = True 'Make Excel Application Visible

If WkBkOpen = True Then 'Check If workbook is open
    Set ExWb = GetObject(FileName).Application
Else:
    Set ExWb = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
End If

AttachFolder = ExWb.Sheets("Email Manager").Range("AttachFolder").Value 'Attachments folder
EmailRow = ExWb.Sheets("Inbox").Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Available Row in Workbook
EmailText = Item.Body
If ExWb.Sheets("Email Manager").Range("Z8") = True Then 'Remove HTML Code
    Dim StartChar As Long
    Dim EndChar As Long
    Do While InStr(EmailText, "<") <> 0
        StartChar = InStr(EmailText, "<") - 1
        EndChar = InStr(EmailText, ">") + 1
        On Error GoTo ReplaceDone
        EmailText = Replace(EmailText, Mid(EmailText, StartChar, EndChar - StartChar), "")
        Loop
ReplaceDone:
End If

With ExWb.Sheets("Inbox") 'Email Sheet
    .Range("A" & EmailRow).Value = Item.ReceivedTime 'Email Received On
    .Range("B" & EmailRow).Value = Item.SenderEmailAddress 'From Email
    .Range("C" & EmailRow).Value = Item.SenderName 'From Name
    .Range("D" & EmailRow).Value = Item.Subject 'Subject
    .Range("E" & EmailRow).Value = EmailText 'Message
    .Range("F" & EmailRow).Value = Item.Importance 'Set Importance
    .Range("H" & EmailRow).Value = "=Row()" 'Row

PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"
Set oPA = Item.propertyaccessor
Responded = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)
 If (Not (Responded = 102)) And (Not (Responded = 103)) Then
    .Range("I" & EmailRow).Value = "INCOMING"
    Else
    .Range("I" & EmailRow).Value = "REPLIED"
End If  
End With


'Add Attachments (if any)
If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    'Check For Senders Name Attachments Folder and add if needed
    If Dir(AttachFolder & "\" & Item.SenderName, vbDirectory) = "" Then 'If attach folder does not exist, Create Folder
        MkDir AttachFolder & "\" & Item.SenderName  'Add Folder if needed
    End If
    
    With ExWb.Sheets("Attachments") 'Attachments Sheet
        AttachRow = ExWb.Sheets("Attachments").Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Available Row in Attachments
        For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
        Attach.SaveAsFile AttachFolder & "\" & Item.SenderName & "\" & Attach.FileName
            .Range("A" & AttachRow).Value = Item.SenderEmailAddress 'Email address
            .Range("B" & AttachRow).Value = Item.SenderName 'Name of Sender
            .Range("C" & AttachRow).Value = Item.ReceivedTime
            .Range("D" & AttachRow).Value = Attach.FileName
            .Range("E" & AttachRow).Value = Right(Attach.FileName, Len(Attach.FileName) - InStrRev(Attach.FileName, ".")) 'Get File Extension /Type
            .Range("F" & AttachRow).Value = AttachFolder & "\" & Item.SenderName & "\" & Attach.FileName 'Full File Path
            AttachRow = AttachRow + 1
        Next Attach
    End With
    
End If
  
    ExWb.Sheets("Inbox").Range("G" & EmailRow).Value = Item.Attachments.Count 'Add In Attachments Count
    ExWb.Sheets("Inbox").Range("A" & EmailRow & ":H" & EmailRow).WrapText = False 'Wrap Text
    

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemAdd` event *is triggered* when an item(s) is added to the folder. It can be received (a brand new mail item), moved, copied and etc. But in case of *brand new mail items* you will not find the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` property value which stands for the last verb executed set on the item. The property may not exist at all for the newly received items.

The property makes sense only for existing items in your Inbox that was replied, forwarded and etc. but not received (brand new).

You may try getting the conversation object (see [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method) to iterate over all items in the conversation and check the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` property value. The newest one (received) will not have this property set up because it has never been replied or forwarded, only received.

Comment: Thank you, I've got more clarity on the subject now, and it makes sense for a replied message to be tagged rather than an incoming mail.

Answer (score 0):

`PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` would not be present on a new message. The property is added only after the user replies to or forwards the email.

Note that since you are using `On Error Resume Next`, all errors get hidden. `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` returns an exception if the specified property is not found. You need to expect and handle that instead of eating all errors.
Also note that you did not handle forwarded emails:

```
    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"
    Set oPA = Item.PropertyAccessor
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next 'hide errors 
    Responded = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)
    If Err.Nomber <> 0 Then
      Responded = 0
      Err.Clear
      On Error GoTo 0 'disable automatic error handling
    End If
    If  (Responded = 102) Or (Responded = 103) Then
        .Range("I" & EmailRow).Value = "REPLIED"
    ElseIf  (Responded = 104)  Then
        .Range("I" & EmailRow).Value = "FORWARDED"
    Else
        .Range("I" & EmailRow).Value = "INCOMING"    
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have a better understanding of the DASL property now, and it might not suit the needs of the use case.